# Reuse already entered components in Strapi

Tags: strapi

I'm bit new to Strapi so I was wondering if it's possible to reuse components.

Here is the scenario I had in mind:

1. Create Page (Content Type entry) - Example page 1
2. Create Sections (Dynamic zone) and add it to Page (Content Type)
3. Create and add couple of components (ex.: Jumbotron, List etc.) and add them to Sections (Dynamic zone)
4. Start adding content to Page -> Sections: Create Jumbotron with title Jumbotron 1
5. Create new Page (Content Type entry) - Example page 2
6. Instead of entering same data I want to reuse Jumbotron 1

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You mean re-use the contents of a component? You can achieve that by making a ContentType for Jumbotron, create an entry there. In the component you create in the page, instead of filling the content you create a relationship

Comment: I did notice that this is possible but this way to need to create empty component with just one relation field. It's an option but not really user friendly (take into consideration the people using this would not be tech savvy).

Comment: Think that is probably just a matter of teaching them. I think the only way to re-use content right now is by creating a relation